# Status bar background color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am trying to make my status bar background color the same as my navigation bar, I was trying to find the answer in google but it does not work clearly for me... Can you please explain how it works and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: As an addendum to your post, it's worth clarifying that the status bar doesn't actually have a colour on iOS. Instead, it's transparent, and it's down to you to make sure your view puts a meaningful colour behind it. In your case, it's this orange-ish colour, but you could (if you chose to) add a white box at the top behind the status bar. I would suggest that the `UINavigationController` is easier and cleaner, but there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a `UINavigationBar` up there, which is what's causing the gap at the top. If you are able to, embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController` instead, then set your navigation item buttons in code. This gives you the same effect, but also automatically ensures the status bar matches the look of its navigation bar.

Comment: @AntonSergeyev: Glad it worked! Don't forget to mark my answer as correct so others can benefit too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Goto your app info.plist

1) Set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
2) Set Status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent

Then Goto your app delegate and paste the following code where you set your Windows's RootViewController.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
    }
```