# React native status bar background color not set

Tags: react-native, statusbar

I'm trying to set the status bar navigation backgroundcolor inside a `renderSectionHeader` function:

```
renderSectionHeader() {
    return (
        <View>
            <StatusBar
              backgroundColor="purple"
              barStyle="light-content"
            />
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Company</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

First of all, it doesn't seem like the right place to set `StatusBar` properties. The `barStyle` property works though, but `backgroundColor` is not set. It's transparant & the actual problem is a `ListView` that scrolls behind the status bar. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265413/status-bar-background-color) SO question, a `UINavigationController` is suggested. But I couldn't find a working implementation.

**Initial**:
[image: Status bar initial]
**Scolled**:
[image: Status bar scrolled]

Answer (score 1):

The backgroundColor property is android only see http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/statusbar.html#backgroundcolor .

Maybe try to add a margin top property on the listview with the height of status bar.